# Unwrap inner type when enum variant is known

Tags: enums, rust

I have this enum type:

```
enum Animal {
    Dog(i32),
    Cat(u8),
}
```

Now I have a function that takes this type as parameter. I *know* (for some reason) that the input is always a `Cat`. I want to achieve this:

```
fn count_legs_of_cat(animal: Animal) -> u8 {
    if let Animal::Cat(c) = animal { c } else { unreachable!() }
}
```

Can I write this shorter and/or more idiomatic?

Comment: As of 2019, this code actually does work on stable - enums were improved since this question was asked. See: <https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f4d6211a7a5c6e9dae6e97114d53dd07>

Comment: @alias65536 The code worked back then, too. The question was rather about whether there exists a better way of doing that.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

What I have seen is to introduce a new `struct` for each enum variant, and then methods on the enum to decompose it:

```rust
struct Dog(i32);
struct Cat(u8);

enum Animal {
    Dog(Dog),
    Cat(Cat),
}

impl Animal {
    fn cat(self) -> Cat {
        if let Animal::Cat(c) = self {
            c
        } else {
            panic!("Not a cat")
        }
    }

    fn dog(self) -> Dog {
        if let Animal::Dog(d) = self {
            d
        } else {
            panic!("Not a dog")
        }
    }
}

// Or better an impl on `Cat` ?
fn count_legs_of_cat(c: Cat) -> u8 {
    c.0
}
```

You don't *need* the struct as you could just return the `u8`, but that may get hard to keep track of. If you have multiple variants with the same inner type, then it would potentially be ambigous.

Over the years, there have been a number of RFCs to provide language support for this (a recent one being [RFC 2593 — Enum variant types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2593)). The proposal would  allow enum variants like `Animal::Cat` to also be standalone types, thus your method could accept an `Animal::Cat` directly.

---

I almost always prefer to write the infallible code in my inherent implementation and force the caller to panic:

```rust
impl Animal {
    fn cat(self) -> Option<Cat> {
        if let Animal::Cat(c) = self {
            Some(c)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    fn dog(self) -> Option<Dog> {
        if let Animal::Dog(d) = self {
            Some(d)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

I'd probably use a `match`:

```rust
impl Animal {
    fn cat(self) -> Option<Cat> {
        match self {
            Animal::Cat(c) => Some(c),
            _ => None,
        }
    }

    fn dog(self) -> Option<Dog> {
        match self {
            Animal::Dog(d) => Some(d),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

Since Rust 1.34, I'd use the [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) trait in addition to or instead of the inherent implementations:

```rust
impl TryFrom<Animal> for Cat {
    type Error = Animal;
    
    fn try_from(other: Animal) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match other {
            Animal::Cat(c) => Ok(c),
            a => Err(a),
        }
    }
}

impl TryFrom<Animal> for Dog {
    type Error = Animal;
    
    fn try_from(other: Animal) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match other {
            Animal::Dog(d) => Ok(d),
            a => Err(a),
        }
    }
}
```

Consider using a dedicated error type that implements `std::error::Error` instead of directly returning the `Animal` in the failure case. You may also want to implement `From` to go from `Cat` / `Dog` back to `Animal`.

This can all get tedious, so a macro can be of good use. I'm sure there are plenty of good crates out that that do this, but I often write my own one-off solution:

```rust
macro_rules! enum_thing {
    (
        enum $Name:ident {
            $($Variant:ident($f:ident)),* $(,)?
        }
    ) => {
        enum $Name {
            $($Variant($Variant),)*
        }

        $(
            struct $Variant($f);

            impl TryFrom<$Name> for $Variant {
                type Error = $Name;

                fn try_from(other: $Name) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
                    match other {
                        $Name::$Variant(v) => Ok(v),
                        o => Err(o),
                    }
                }
            }
        )*
    };
}

enum_thing! {
    enum Animal {
        Dog(i32),
        Cat(u8),
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of the impl Animal I tend to impl the Into trait, like [this playground example](http://is.gd/jmS3RB). With simple enums it should be relatively easy to have a macro to generate the impls, but it's not a pattern I use all that much, so I never actually got around to writing it...

Comment: is it possible to extend the macro to variants having multiple named fields?

Comment: for named fields: https://gist.github.com/BenFradet/0ae3d7610d8c488bf41c772eb94909d0

Answer (score 18):

Try the [enum-as-inner](https://crates.io/crates/enum-as-inner) crate. It generates accessor methods as suggested in [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34954128).

Here is example usage loosely based on the crate's README:

```rust
use enum_as_inner::EnumAsInner;

#[derive(Debug, EnumAsInner)]
enum MyEnum {
    Zero,
    One(u32),
    Two(u32, i32),
    Three { a: bool, b: u32, c: i64 },
}

fn main() {
    let zero = MyEnum::Zero;
    assert!(zero.is_zero());

    let one = MyEnum::One(1);
    assert_eq!(one.into_one().unwrap(), 1);

    let mut two = MyEnum::Two(1, 2);
    *two.as_two_mut().unwrap().0 = 42;  // Set the first field to 42

    let three = MyEnum::Three { a: true, b: 1, c: 2 };
    assert_eq!(three.into_three().unwrap(), (true, 1, 2));
}
```

As of v0.6.0 of the crate, the methods generated include:

- `fn is_FIELDNAME(&self) -> bool`
- `fn as_FIELDNAME(&self) -> Option<&T>`
- `fn as_FIELDNAME_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut T>`
- `fn into_FIELDNAME(self) -> Result<T, Self>`
  where `T` is the inner type corresponding to the named field.

Comment: Maybe you could add an example showing how the crate could be used?

Answer (score 15):

I found one single macro is the best way to solve the problem (in recent Rust).

**Macro Definition**

```rust
    macro_rules! cast {
        ($target: expr, $pat: path) => {
            {
                if let $pat(a) = $target { // #1
                    a
                } else {
                    panic!(
                        "mismatch variant when cast to {}", 
                        stringify!($pat)); // #2
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

**Macro Usage**

```rust
let cat = cast!(animal, Animal::Cat);
```

**Explanation:**

- #1 The if let exploits recent Rust compiler's smart pattern matching. Contrary to other solutions like `into_variant` and friends, this one macro covers all ownership usage like `self`, `&self` and `&mut self`. On the other hand `{into,as,as_mut}_{variant}` solution usually needs 3 * N method definitions where N is the number of variants.
- #2 If the variant and value mismatch, the macro will simply panic and report the expected pattern.
- The macro, however, does not handle nested pattern like `Some(Animal(cat))`. But it is good enough for common usage.

Comment: I like it - but would love it if it would work for struct-style enums too:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=645ebd48ece598ee0d7c2fa980a57d91

Answer (score 5):

This is not shorter with this simple method, but if you have a lot of processing to do on the data, you can use `let`-`else`, stabilized in Rust 1.65.0:

```rust
fn count_legs_of_cat(animal: Animal) -> u8 {
    let Animal::Cat(c) = animal else {
        unreachable!()
    };
    c
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a small macro for extracting the known enum variant:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! extract_enum_value {
  ($value:expr, $pattern:pat => $extracted_value:expr) => {
    match $value {
      $pattern => $extracted_value,
      _ => panic!("Pattern doesn't match!"),
    }
  };
}

let cat = extract_enum_value!(animal, Animal::Cat(c) => c);
```

However, I'm not sure if this fits into your need.

Comment: Very useful! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

The [`derive_more`](https://jeltef.github.io/derive_more/derive_more/) crate exports a `TryInto` derive macro that generates implementations of the standard library's [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) trait. The trait enables conversion from the given enum type to the inner type wrapped by a given variant.

Here is a usage example [from the `derive_more::TryInto` docs](https://jeltef.github.io/derive_more/derive_more/try_into.html):

```rust
use core::convert::TryFrom;
use core::convert::TryInto;
#[derive(TryInto, Clone)]
#[try_into(owned, ref, ref_mut)]
enum MixedData {
    Int(u32),
    String(String),
}

fn main() {
    let string = MixedData::String("foo".to_string());
    let int = MixedData::Int(123);
    assert_eq!(Ok(123u32), int.clone().try_into());
    assert_eq!(Ok(&123u32), (&int.clone()).try_into());
    assert_eq!(Ok(&mut 123u32), (&mut int.clone()).try_into());
    assert_eq!("foo".to_string(), String::try_from(string.clone()).unwrap());
    assert!(u32::try_from(string).is_err());
}
```

This approach could be combined with the [`enum-as-inner`](https://crates.io/crates/enum-as-inner) crate mentioned in [@Black Marco's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66112628) which generates accessor methods with names corresponding to the enum variants.