# Read from an enum without pattern matching

Tags: enums, rust, discriminated-union

The Rust [documentation gives this example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.6.0/book/patterns.html) where we have an instance of `Result<T, E>` named `some_value`:

```
match some_value {
    Ok(value) => println!("got a value: {}", value),
    Err(_) => println!("an error occurred"),
}
```

Is there any way to read from `some_value` without pattern matching? What about without even checking the type of the contents at runtime? Perhaps we somehow know with absolute certainty what type is contained or perhaps we're just being a bad programmer. In either case, I'm just curious to know if it's at all possible, not if it's a good idea.

It strikes me as a really interesting language feature that this branch is so difficult (or impossible?) to avoid.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34953711/unwrap-inner-type-when-enum-variant-is-known

Answer (score 33, accepted):

At the lowest level, no, you can't read enum fields without a `match`<sup>1</sup>.

Methods on an enum can provide more convenient access to data within the enum (e.g. [`Result::unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap)), but under the hood, they're always implemented with a `match`.

If you know that a particular case in a `match` is unreachable, a common practice is to write [`unreachable!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.unreachable.html) on that branch (`unreachable!()` simply expands to a `panic!()` with a specific message).

---

<sup>1</sup> If you have an enum with only one variant, you could also write a simple `let` statement to deconstruct the enum. Patterns in `let` and `match` statements must be exhaustive, and pattern matching the single variant from an enum is exhaustive. But enums with only one variant are pretty much never used; a struct would do the job just fine. And if you intend to add variants later, you're better off writing a `match` right away.

```
enum Single {
    S(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let a = Single::S(1);
    let Single::S(b) = a;
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

On the other hand, if you have an enum with more than one variant, you can also use `if let` and `while let` if you're interested in the data from a single variant only. While `let` and `match` require exhaustive patterns, `if let` and `while let` accept non-exhaustive patterns. You'll often see them used with `Option`:

```
fn main() {
    if let Some(x) = std::env::args().len().checked_add(1) {
        println!("{}", x);
    } else {
        println!("too many args :(");
    }
}
```