# Is there a macro I can use to expect a variant of an enum and extract its data?

Tags: rust, enums, rust-macros

Given an enum like

```rust
struct Earth { water: usize }
struct Mars { redness: usize }

enum World {
    Mars(Mars),
    Earth(Earth),
}
```

A common pattern I write is

```rust
fn something_expecting_mars(planet: World) {
    let mars = match planet {
        World::Mars(data) => data,
        _ => panic!("Shouldn't be here now"),
    }
}
```

Is there a macro I can use to expect a variant of an enum and subsequently extract its data?

```rust
// rewriting to this
let mars = expect_v!(planet, World::Mars);
```

Comment: See also [Unwrap inner type when enum variant is known](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34953711/155423)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library provides a macro for [testing a match](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.matches.html), but not one for extracting a value. However, it's fairly easy to write one:

```
macro_rules! expect_v {
    ($e:expr, $p:path) => {
        match $e {
            $p(value) => value,
            _ => panic!("expected {}", stringify!($p)),
        }
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c99fafdf8af4de6a87382f63e750c3f4)

As suggested in answers to the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34953711/155423) brought up in the comments, you might want to decouple value extraction from the panic. In that case, return an `Option` instead and let the callers panic if they wish by calling `unwrap()`:

```
macro_rules! extract {
    ($e:expr, $p:path) => {
        match $e {
            $p(value) => Some(value),
            _ => None,
        }
    };
}

// ...
fn something_expecting_mars(planet: World) {
    let mars = extract!(planet, World::Mars).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! In the `panic`, is it possible to print the expected vs actual path name?

Comment: @user82395214 Printing what was expected is fairly easy using `stringify!()`, I've now amended the answer to use it. I don't think it's possible to print the actual variant, at least not with a declarative macro. But if you're ok with requiring `Debug`, you could print the whole value, i.e. change the second match arm to `other => panic!("expected {}, got {:?}", stringify!($p), other)`.

Answer (score -1):

Anything wrong with just using `if let` instead of `match`?

```rust
mars = if let World::Mars(data) = planet { data } else { panic!("Woot woot")}
```

Comment: This should probably be posted a comment, not an answer, since the OP explicitly asked about a macro and even provided the expected usage. Also note that `rustfmt` will reformat this into [four lines](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c536ca44e299a004f16d98b289793315) so it's not particularly elegant.